# .Filter() remove array or arrays when undefined

Tags: arrays, typescript

I got object:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Test",
    "settings": {
      "object": {
        "hoursAvailable": [
          11,
          9,
          14
        ],
        "value": 65
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Test 2",
    "settings": {
      "object": {
        "hoursAvailable": [],
        "value": 65
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Test 3",
    "settings": {
      "object": {
        "value": 65
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I'm figuring out how can i remove all hourAvailable < 10, using .filter or lodash. The problem sometimes i have undefined "hoursAvailable" objects. After filtering i need to have:

```
[
 {
   // other data
   "settings": {
     "object": {
       "hoursAvailable": [
         9, // <- all numbers <10
       ],
       "value": 65
     }
   }
 },
 {
   // other data
   "settings": {
     "object": {
       "hoursAvailable": [],
       "value": 65
     }
   }
 },
 {
   // other data
   "settings": {
     "object": {
       "value": 65
     }
   }
 }
]
```

I'm trying to:

```
.filter(arr => {
arr['settings']['object']['hoursAvailable'] <= 10;
}
```

But it gives me undefined when there's no hoursAvailable object and didnt delete numbers <10 What should i do to delete <10 in ['hoursAvailable']?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by modifying the condition of your filter block.

I have made a JSfiddle for the representation. You can play around with conditions in the filter block to achieve the desired result.

https://jsfiddle.net/harsh89/bru7jyg6/7/

```
var xyz = arr.filter(val => {
return !val.settings.object.hoursAvailable || 

!val.settings.object.hoursAvailable.length  || 

(val.settings.object.hoursAvailable[0] < 10);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but i still get "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'hoursAvailable' of undefined
" when there's no hoursAvailable object... :( / my fault, working! Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but it not what i mean. I updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y0z57atr/

Comment: look at new jsfiddle, please :) jsfiddle.net/y0z57atr